# golang spimple crud web api, do I need to start a go routine for each handler

Tags: go, server

I am writing a simple web api with crud operations in golang (reading and writing from a database).  As part of this do I need to start a go routine for each handler in `HandleFunc` or does the server api handle this automatically for me through `HandleFunc`.  If I need to start a separate go routine I assume I have to use buffered channels for signalling and how do I ensure that the proper context is used to send the request back to the proper client.

I am sorry if this is a basic question but I come from a nodejs background and there this is automatically handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, each handler runs on a goroutine. You need to use mutex or channels to manage access to shared resources.
This article shows how to manage concurrency in a very practical way: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2019/on-concurrency-in-go-http-servers/

Comment: thanks for this, very helpful and what I was looking for.